# Fragment not get correct Controller

Tags: sapui5

I istantiate a fragment by this code in the controller `formAddElement`. (i use `this` to pass current controller)

```
this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("apps.appIntra.fragment.dialogClienti",this);
```

In the same controller i have a function `handleSearch`

```
handleSearch: function(oEvent) {
        var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("RAG_SOC_1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
        var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
        oBinding.filter([oFilter]);
  },
```

when in the fragment i press search the function in the controller not fire.

But if I use

```
this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("apps.appIntra.fragment.dialogClienti", sap.ui.getCore().byId('formAddElement').getController());
```

all work!! WHY??? O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" should work. you need to run F12 debugger in chrome to check what "this" is, whether it is the oController object. it could be other object depending the calling object.