# Pass another controller when instantiating a fragment in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, controller, fragment, sapui5

In the SAPUI5 / OpenUI5 [xmlfragment documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.xmlfragment) the third parameter is a controller for handling actions from the fragment.

This is critical for a dialog fragment where there are buttons to press etc.

Most of the time I have seen this instantiated as `this` or `sap.ui.getCore().byId('<element>').getController())`

See an example at [Fragment not get correct Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203225/fragment-not-get-correct-controller)

Because of the complexity in a particular dialog I would like to have a separate controller for it.

I have looked around at this and had a few attempts but so far not successful.

I have put a working example on [github](https://github.com/njames/DialogTest) of using `this`.

But I would like to instantiate `Dialog.js` as the controller for the `Dialog.fragment.xml` from `initial.view.controller`

Any takers?

Pull requests gladly received.

The Crux of the example is as follows (this is the initial.controller.js) :

```
sap.ui.controller("sc.test.view.initial", {

oDialog: null,

openTestDialog: function(){
    console.log("in open dialog");
     // instantiate the other controller
     var oDialogController = new sc.test.view.Dialog();
    // this next commented line is the 'normal' way to do it
    // oDialog = new sap.ui.xmlfragment( "sc.test.view.Dialog", this);  //oDialogController);
    // this is what I would like to achieve
    oDialog = new sap.ui.xmlfragment( "sc.test.view.Dialog", oDialogController);
    oDialog.open();
},       


onCartDialogCancel:function(oEvent){
// this function would then be in the other controller but how to get a handle on the dialog?
    oDialog.close();

}
```

});

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the (simplified) example you have got here too. (Stackoverflow policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just got to SYD airport)

All you're missing is the

```
jQuery.sap.require("sc.test.view.Dialog");
```

in your `initial.controller.js`.

Pushed a quick fix in a branch to your repo and opened a [PR](https://github.com/njames/DialogTest/pull/1)

Answer (score 2):

only example i could find close to yours was in the Material Shortage Fiori app

```
  oCtrl = sap.ui.controller("myapp.fragments.DirectCallDialog");
  oDirectCallDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("myapp.fragments.DirectCallDialog", oCtrl);
```

lots of examples of injecting a controller when the fragment was called from a helper class. The helper class promotes reuse, eg same dialog fragment can be called from multiple views/components. The helper class method for the dialog setup is called from within a controller and the oController parameter is set to 'this'.

hth
jsp

Answer (score 2):

I copied an existing controller.js, and renamed it.

Then, instantiated that as a below, and passed it through with the fragment.

var oNewController = new sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller("myProject.DialogController");
this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("myPopup","myProject.fragments.myPopup", oNewController);

All eventing is now handled in oNewController, rather than the previously used "this"...